# What's wrong with Spring's @RequestBody byte[] (length bigger than expected)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, base64, arrays, converters

I tried to use `@RequestBody byte[] data` as automatic Base64 decoder, in order to receive some RSA encrypted data and afterwards decrypt it in my service:

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping
void doIt(@RequestBody byte[] data) {
    service.doIt(data);
}
```

**Service:**

```
void doIt(byte[] encryptedData) {               
    String testDataString = "hgLGtzF4D8tlJbVivQgaXXwfI9TbQ//PrYHEez5k93sqJSi17eLCa+r/cGNGvoxDRaPYONvP4yxW0ajKDFrusQ4V4owfhkijS9KzBOTjBeAVmA+5jBsZCdoxwCA65DiP5lJ+GRbn8CjcjCr4DaEWFbWHsyvY4NGGAQLuYv+PyZipfU9pXTEDsBb15NwaHlD5m7Z4CHWdWTt1ARvRaQs56Bp63/IEmGR7w4brA1+iuKPv83FLh0rsxyoJ+F8TeqtuPhm2fHTh1FiHn0Bpaqqoyd/cBl0/utSzu4qoZhB3AiVgLjnT6Iy9p5nVoAozxQo/Es59LrpGZfjYJer073jNIg==";
    byte[] testDataBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(testDataString);

    System.out.println(encryptedData.length);
    System.out.println(testDataBytes.length);

    System.out.println(new String(encryptedData).length());
    System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(testDataBytes).length());

    System.out.println(new String(encryptedData).equals(Base64.encodeBase64String(testDataBytes)));
}
```

**Request:**

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Request Payload: 
hgLGtzF4D8tlJbVivQgaXXwfI9TbQ//PrYHEez5k93sqJSi17eLCa+r/cGNGvoxDRaPYONvP4yxW0ajKDFrusQ4V4owfhkijS9KzBOTjBeAVmA+5jBsZCdoxwCA65DiP5lJ+GRbn8CjcjCr4DaEWFbWHsyvY4NGGAQLuYv+PyZipfU9pXTEDsBb15NwaHlD5m7Z4CHWdWTt1ARvRaQs56Bp63/IEmGR7w4brA1+iuKPv83FLh0rsxyoJ+F8TeqtuPhm2fHTh1FiHn0Bpaqqoyd/cBl0/utSzu4qoZhB3AiVgLjnT6Iy9p5nVoAozxQo/Es59LrpGZfjYJer073jNIg==
```

**The Output:**

```
(Spring) Byte length:          344
(test)   Byte length:          256
(Spring) Base64 String length: 344
(test)   Base64 String length: 344
         Base64 String equals: true
```

As you can see:

- The request contains exactly the same data as the test data I put into the source code.
- After doing Base64 encoding both have the same length and are `equal``
- **BUT:** The length of the byte arrays are different.

## Question:

Why is the `byte[]` that was generated by Spring bigger? (It's useless when trying to decode it using some RSA private key, because RSA expects a length of 256.)

### Workaround:

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping
void doIt(@RequestBody String data) {
    service.doIt(Base64.decodeBase64(data));
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. The output you give is unrelated to the test code you show, and this test code doesn't make any sense to me: `new String(encryptedData)` for example doesn't make any sense.

Comment: There are 5 `System.out.println(...)` in my test code. And there are 5 values (`344`, `256`, `344`, `344`, `true`) in the Output. Using `new String(byte[])` you can transform a byte array to String. Java doc says: *Constructs a new {@code String} by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset.*. I just use it to clarify the problem. ... The problem I tried describe is: Spring's HttpMessageConverter constructs a byte array that is larger then it should be. And if you're using something that depends on every single bit (like RSA decryption), it simply doesn't work.

Comment: But the byte array doesn't contain characters encoded to bytes using your default platform encoding. It contains arbitrary, binary bytes, that don't represent valid characters. Anyway, you're assuming that Spring base64 decodes  the request body to bind it to a byte array. That's not the case. It reads the stream of bytes in the request as is, without doing any decoding.

Comment: But somehow it does decode it. As shown in my code sample, I've got `@RequestBody byte[] data` and then I simply do `new String(data)`. And if I use `System.out.println(new String(data))` I can see the same String I used as payload in my request. So somehow it works. And even the `equals` method returns `true`.

Comment: So, you send a base64 string, Spring reads it as a byte array, then you're constructing a String from this byte array, and seeing the base64 string that you sent, right? If so, that clearly means that Spring does not decode anything. If it decoded you would be able to take a byte array (containing, let's say 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), base-64 encode it (which would produce the string "AQIDBAU=", send it in the request, and see [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] as the byte array).

Comment: Yes you're right. I send a base64 encoded String as request body, read it in my Controller as `@RequestBody byte[]` and afterwards just print it as `new String(byte[])`. ... Btw: I just took a look at the byte[] HttpMessageConverter and there's the reason why Springs generated byte[] is larger than it should be: It constructs a byte[] with length = length of request body. As you can see from my output above, the generated byte[] has length=344 and also my request body string has length=344.

Comment: "It constructs a byte[] with length = length of request body" - of course. How could it construct smaller array when you actually send it 344 bytes of content? You're missing the point here.

You send 344 bytes. That's why array is 344 bytes long.

I know the bytes in this case represent ASCII characters, that make a 344 character long String, which is a BASE64 encoded version of 255 bytes. But Spring doesn't know that and doesn't care, and doesn't decode your BASE64 encoded content.

If you want 255 bytes from Spring don't send 344 bytes of BASE64 encoded content - send those 255 bytes!

Comment: What you seem to fail to realize is that HTTP request with Content-Type: application/octet-stream should NOT have BASE64 encoded data, but should have raw bytes there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spring's `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`, you can find the method `readInternal` which converts the contents of a request into the desired format (in this case `byte[]`).

**The code** (Spring 4.0.0.RELEASE)**:**

```
long contentLength = inputMessage.getHeaders().getContentLength();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(contentLength >= 0 ? (int) contentLength : StreamUtils.BUFFER_SIZE);
StreamUtils.copy(inputMessage.getBody(), bos);
return bos.toByteArray();
```

The second line says: *If the request payload isn't empty take it's content length, and set the capacity of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` with that. Else if the content length is < 0, then set it to StreamUtils.BUFFER_SIZE (= 4096).*

Im not really sure why it is implemented this way, but that's how it actually works.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. The problem author has is that he somehow assumes Spring will decode his 344 characters long BASE64 encoded string, but Spring doesn't do that, it just creates a byte array with 1 byte for each character.

Comment: its implemented that way because without content type header it doesnt know how much memory to allocate, so it allocates 4K. if you know the size, specify the content length